# ¿Cómo seleccionar varios elementos con una misma clase desde JavaScript? Y además agregarle estilos

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

El problema es el siguiente, estoy tratando de seleccionar varios elementos con una misma clase y una vez seleccionados los elementos agregarle otra clase con estilos definidos.

Esto lo hago de la siguiente manera:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-button">
  <button id="google-search-button" class="btn">Buscar con Google</button>
  <button id="i-feel-lucky" class="btn">Me siento con suerte</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main
.container-button
.btn-dark {
    background-color: #303134; 
    color: #e4e6e9; 
    border: none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
const theme = document.getElementById("theme");
theme.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
  const button = document.querySelector(".btn");
  button.classList.add("btn-dark");
})
```

El problema es que este código solo me agrega los estilos al *primer elemento*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y si cambio la forma en que secciono los elementos HTML con la clase, para poder seleccionar todos, no me funciona:

**JavaScript**

```
const theme = document.getElementById("theme");
theme.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
  const button = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
  button.classList.add("btn-dark");
})
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que puedan ayudarme.

Comment: [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) te devuelve una lista de nodos, no puedes asignar directamente estilos, tienes que recorrer para hacerlo uno por uno, como en el [ejemplo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), dentro del `forEach` es donde agregas la nueva clase.

Comment: ¿Esta sería la sintaxis? `const button = document.querySelectorAll(".btn"); button.forEach(function() {button.classList.add("btn-dark");});`

Comment: @FrancoAgustínCarballar, tenes un error, fijate como se usar [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, ya lo pude resolver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gracias a la ayuda de @Triby lo puede resolver de la siguiente manera:

**JavaScipt**

```
const button = [...document.querySelectorAll(".btn")];
button.forEach(function(elemento, index, arreglo) {
  arreglo[0].classList.add("btn-dark");
  arreglo[1].classList.add("btn-dark");
});
```

Comment: Con un solo parámetro es suficiente, `elemento` y, dentro de la función `elemento.classList.add('btn-dark');`